# Are there any flash media players that have frame-by-frame functionality?

Tags: flash, media-player

The player can be free or commercial, frame-by-frame can be core functionality or a plug-in. Also, it must be production quality and handle [RTMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Time_Messaging_Protocol) streaming.

Comment: You mean other than the proper Adobe Flash player?

Comment: The Adobe Flash plug-in plays Flash files, but not videos. I'm specifically talking about a media player build using Flash technology. An example of this is YouTube's media player implementation or JW FLV Player or Flowplayer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By virtue of how the Flash-based video formats work you won't see frame-by-frame as a native capability.

The problem is that of keyframes. A keyframe specifies all of the data for that frame. Every N number of frames (where N is specified by the person who encoded the video) in a video there is a keyframe, the frames in between just specify delta information from the last keyframe. This why, for example, scrubbing in most flash-based video players is less than precise.

In order to do frame-by-frame scrubbing the video player would have to maintain an off screen buffer to play the video and capture the delta frames to BitmapData objects. I'm fairly sure this would work, it just may be a little slow.

I know this isn't a direct answer to your question but it should at least push you in the right direction for what to look for or develop yourself.

Answer (score 0):

here you go. http://davidwees.com/myblog/2007/05/frame_by_frame_player_in_flash.html

Comment: Thanks, but that only works with a video embedded in the SWF file and it isn't Production quality. I have modified my question to add these conditions.